# Drupal Or Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, drupal

I am in process to build a website, which includes following functionality.
Front-end user-
1. User registration (admin approval).
2. User can ask question.
3. User can search about articles or whole website.
4. User can add article to Bookmark list, wishlist, favorite list etc.

Admin Panel-
1. Admin can add/delete/update user.
2. Admin would able to put replies to user's questions.
3. Admin would be able to add/edit/delete articles.
4. Admin can send bulk emails.
5. Admin would get notification whenever user post new questions.

So, my concern is  which platform should i choose, Drupal OR CakePhp ?

Please advice me, i am new to both one.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP is framework for developing PHP applications. You can use it for what you are describing but you would have to build all those components yourself.

Drupal is a content management system which already can do some of what you are asking. You can extend it to support your additional requirements.

Comment: Yes, i am agree with you, but there are a level of customization will occur into the admin panel, as there would  be some analytic calculation like -  1. Which Information sheets are being most searched
2. Which schools are doing the most searching
3. Which job roles are doing most searching
4. Which information headings are most people searching on
5. Which types of schools are doing most searching, so with which one it would be easier?

Comment: We don't recommend software here @BanshiL.Dangi, and it's impossible to tell you what's easier. It depends what you know.